# Angular 15 Ckeditor disabled

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I'm trying to disable Ckeditor in my application but it prompt error.

```
<ckeditor formControlName="content" [editor]="Editor" [config]="ckConfig" required></ckeditor>
```

```
 this.form.controls['content'].disable();
```

However I received error "this.editorInstance.enableReadOnlyMode is not a function". I'm using Angular 15.

Comment: cant you use the disabled attribute? `<ckeditor [disabled]="true">`

Comment: Could you check if your `ckeditor` version is compatible with Angular 15? https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/integrations/angular.html#supported-angular-versions